# How do you find the limit of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}$?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, problem-solving

**My attempt:**

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(\frac{\tan x}{x}-\frac{\sin x}{x})$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1-1)$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\times 0$$

$$0$$

However, according to [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Limit%22%2C%20%22limitfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%28tan%28x%29-sin%28x%29%29%2F%28x%5E3%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Limit%22%2C%20%22limit%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22) and my book, I'm wrong. The correct answer is $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Questions:**

1. Why did I get the wrong answer in my process?
2. What would be the correct way to solve the problem?

**Solution to a similar problem:**

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{\sin^3x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\sin x}{\sin^3x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x-\cos x.\sin x}{\cos x}}{\sin^3x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin x-\cos x.\sin x}{\cos x.\sin^3x}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-\cos x)}{\cos x.\sin^2x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-\cos x)}{\cos x(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: **Error** In the last step, the limit is in 'indeterminant form'  that is $\infty.  0 $ and does not equal to $0.$

Comment: @user10354138 Iìm not sure that the target duplicate is an exact duplicate for this question. Here the OP is asking for the mistake in their derivation. Moreover the OP is also already showing a way to solve a similar problem which is almost a solution for the presented one.

Comment: @user10354138 I agree that the one you selected is strictly related but it doesn't address the question posed by the OP. For this reason I'm going to vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way is wrong because you are taking the limit not at once for the whole expression and this is not allowed in general.

We have that

$$\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}=\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{\sin^3x}\frac{\sin^3x}{x^3}$$

then we can use the second solution you have shown.

For the mistake in the first solution refer also to

- [Analyzing limits problem Calculus (tell me where I'm wrong).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783782/505767)

and to the related

- [Trig limit without L'Hospital Rule: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/950236/505767)

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in the equality$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{x^2}\left(\frac{\tan x}x-\frac{\sin x}x\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{x^2}(1-1).$$You cannot take the limit at $0$ in part of your expression and leave the $x$ in the remaining expression.

You have\begin{align}\require{cancel}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{x^3}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(\cancel x+\frac13x^3+O(x^4)\right)-\left(\cancel x-\frac16x^3+O(x^4)\right)}{x^3}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12x^3+O(x^4)}{x^3}\\&=\frac12.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{aligned} & \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^{3}}\left(\frac{0}{0}\right) \\=& \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sec ^{2} x-\cos x}{3 x^{2}}\left(\frac{0}{0}\right) \\=& \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2 \sec ^{2} x \tan x+\sin x}{6 x} \end{aligned}$

$ \displaystyle =\frac{1}{6}\left(2 \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \sec ^{2} x \cdot \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan x}{x}+\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\right)$

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{6}(2 \cdot 1+1)$

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{2}$